# What does std::find return if element not found

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, iterator

As per documentation, `std::find` returns

> last

if no element is found. What does that mean? Does it return an iterator pointing to the last element in the container? Or does it return an iterator pointing to `.end()`, i.e. pointing outside the container?
The following code prints `0`, which is not an element of the container. So, I guess `std::find` returns an iterator outside the container. Could you please confirm?

```
int main()
{
    vector<int> vec = {1, 2,3, 1000, 4, 5};
    auto itr = std::find(vec.begin(), vec.end(), 456);
    cout << *itr;
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`last` is the name of second parameter to `find`. It doesn't know what kind of container you're using, just the iterators that you give it.

In your example, `last` is `vec.end()`, which is (by definition) not dereferenceable, since it's one past the last element. So by dereferencing it, you invoke undefined behaviour, which in this case manifests as printing out 0.

Comment: However, you should be able to do `if find(vec.begin(), vec.end(), ...) != vec.end()`...

Comment: Whatever the type of vec is,does *(vec.end()) always return 0?@First Jens @Cameron

Comment: @Yuan: No. Since dereferencing `vec.end()` is *undefined behaviour*, it could return a different value each time. Or crash. Or corrupt some other memory elsewhere but appear to return something reasonable. Or, or, or... ;-) In this particular case, dereferencing it is probably causing whatever happens to be in memory after the vector's elements to be interpreted as an element, which was 0 at the time, but could easily have been any garbage value.

Comment: So for every iterator,if we want to do *iterator,we'd better make sure it's valid?The code posted by First Jens has some bug?@Cameron

Comment: @Yuan: Yes, exactly. First Jens was missing a compare of the result of `find` against `vec.end()` before dereferencing the iterator.

Answer (score 3):

Algorithms apply to **ranges**, which are defined by a pair of iterators. Those iterators are passed as arguments to the algorithm. The first iterator points at the first element in the range, and the second argument points at one past the end of the range. Algorithms that can fail return a copy of the past-the-end iterator when they fail. That's what `std::find` does: if there is no matching element it returns its second argument.

Note that the preceding paragraph does **not** use the word "container". Containers have member functions that give you a range that you can use to get at the elements of the container, but there are also ways of creating iterators that have no connection to any container.

Comment: You don't use container,so which one do you use?Algorithms or ranges?@Pete Becker

Comment: @YuanWen -- The **specification** for the algorithm does not use containers. The algorithm can be applied to the contents of a container by calling it with iterators that point into the container. You get those iterators by calling `begin()` and `end()` on the container.

Answer (score 1):

Based on [**this**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) documentation, it literally says:

*"Return value:
Iterator to the first element satisfying the condition or last if no such element is found."*

In your case, it's out the vector by one, `.end()`